# How to copy all active cells from excel and paste it to word document using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to know the selenium code to do thee below

CTRL+A from excel and CTRL + V to the word doc.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium using browser and cant open Microsof Excel from Computer. Try google doc online and api to copy paste